# How to access JSON object in constructor?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6

In the below I am trying to create a `Test` class, where the constructor initializes a JSON object called `documents` and a method `addDocument()` which adds a JSON string to the `documents` JSON object.

The error I am getting is `documents is not defined` in

```
documents[doc.date] = doc;
```

I don't understand how I can get access to `documents` from the `addDocuemnts()` method. Can someone help me out?

```
const wh1 = {
  "key": "a",
  "date": "2021-07-10T08:19:44.391Z",
  "documents": [ {"_id": "aaa"}]
};
const wh2 = {
  "key": "b",
  "date": "2021-07-10T08:19:44.391Z",
  "documents": [ {"_id": "bbb"}]
};

class Test {
  constructor(document) {
    this.document = document;

    let documents = JSON.parse('{}');
    documents[document.date] = document;
  };

  addDocument(doc) {
    documents[doc.date] = doc;
  };

  print() {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(this.documents));
  };
};

const a = new Test(wh1);
a.addDocument(wh2);
a.print();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are never setting `this.documents` on the object itself?

You're currently creating a local variable `let documents` within the constructor which is why it's only available within that function.

```js
const wh1 = {
  "key": "a",
  "date": "2021-07-10T08:19:44.391Z",
  "documents": [ {"_id": "aaa"}]
};
const wh2 = {
  "key": "b",
  "date": "2021-07-10T08:19:44.391Z",
  "documents": [ {"_id": "bbb"}]
};

class Test {
  constructor(document) {
    this.document = document;

    this.documents = JSON.parse('{}');
    this.documents[document.date] = document;
  };

  addDocument(doc) {
    this.documents[doc.date] = doc;
  };

  print() {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(this.documents));
  };
};

const a = new Test(wh1);
a.addDocument(wh2);
a.print();
```